# How do I create a facet_wrap diagram using geom_bar that includes all the variables and their bars in grey color and specific variable in other color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-wrap

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(place = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g", 
                         "h", "h", "i", "i", "j", "j", "k", "k", "l", "l", "m", "m", "n", 
                         "n", "o", "o", "p", "p", "q", "q"), 
               cost_other = c("cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings",
                            "cost_savings", "other_savings"), 
               values = c(1.8,0.55, 0.836, 1.06, 1.096, 1.83875908682016, 
                          0.966, 1.34497094648805, 1.62275, 0.600277163210231, 0.873875, 
                          0.875130680022367, 1.487, 0.283241350805961, 1.0776, 0.849116238360361, 
                          1.221, 1.45510685371131, 0.961882352941176, 1.30607084680655, 
                          1.027, 1.52026452067783, 0.807666666666667, 1.22377282341786, 
                          0.788384615384615, 0.984172521942087, 0.975, 1.94002090880358, 
                          1.00333333333333, 1.18402178405582, 0.8956, 1.16165422673896, 
                          0.95975, 0.825533052928448))
```

I want to create a facet-wrap-based geom_bar chart using these data, such that every faceted space shows all the bar charts in grey color. Then, I need the specific bars for specific grid to be in any color.

I tried doing it, but got something like this:

[image]

I used this to get my result:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=place,
                 y=values))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=cost_other),
       stat = "identity",
       position = "dodge")  +
 facet_wrap(~place) +
 theme_calc()+
 theme(legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

I am getting the specific bars in color, but then all the other spaces are empty. I want other bars for all variables as well, specifically in grey color.

Comment: Your example data doesn't match up with the code or the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `tidyr::expand_grid()`, create a `place_facet` column with unique values of `place` and cross it with the initial data. This will give you an expanded dataframe that reproduces your original data once for each facet. Then plot two layers of bars: one in gray using all values, and another in color for just the values where `place` and `place_facet` match.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

df1 %>%
  tidyr::expand_grid(place_facet = unique(.$place)) %>%
  mutate(values_facet = ifelse(place == place_facet, values, NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = place)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = values, group = cost_other), 
    position = "dodge",
    fill = "gray"
  ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(y = values_facet, fill = cost_other),
    position = "dodge",
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~place_facet) +
  theme_calc() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks so much for such a quick response with an elegant solution.