# How do I data get from each facet superimposed on greyed out background data

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp))  +geom_point(data=mtcars, color='grey') + geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(color=as.factor(gear)))   +facet_wrap(~gear)
```

gives this:
[image]

But what I want is all data greyed out in the background.

This gets closer but makes background data a new facet, I want it in the background of the 3 facets, not as a new one:

```
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) +
  geom_point(data=mtcars %>% mutate(gear = "All"), aes(group=gear), color='grey') +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(gear))) +
  facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image]

Comment: I like @Quinten's solution, but also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75515481/17303805.

Comment: @zephryl, Nice use of `expand_grid`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one `geom_point` with the gear column using `select` and `color` them grey. For the second `geom_point` you could color them by `factor` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp))  + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars %>%
               select(-gear), aes(x = mpg, y = disp), color = 'grey') +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(gear))) +
  facet_wrap(~gear) 
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you want to display "all" to the legend with grey color you could assign the name to the aesthetics with `color` and change the colors with `scale_color_manual` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp))  + 
  geom_point(data = mtcars %>%
               select(-gear), aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = 'all')) +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(gear))) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("3","4","5","all"),
                    values=c("red", "blue", "green", "grey")) + 
  facet_wrap(~gear) 
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>